# when code with rails, how to call a controller method Automatically when the rails project start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the classic rails directory structure, I want to call a controller method in a file in the config directory to ensure the method is called when the rails project start. But I don`t know   how to make it. OR can I call a controller method from somewhere else except the controller directory,not through HTTP request? 
I`m new here and new with rails, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in an initializer

create your `on_start.rb` under the `config/initializers`

write whatever ruby code you want to happen there.

Every time the rails environment loads, that code in the initializer will run.

You don't need a controller for that. The purpose of a controller is connect the models with the views via http verbs. If what you need doesn't result in an http action, it is best to put it in regular ruby code in the initializer

Comment: It's amazing to receive an answer so quickly, thank you! But I'm working on someone else's work, and I need to call the method when the  project start. The method is complicated for me, so it`s a bit difficult for me to recode it in the on_start file.Is there any solution to call it directly? Thank you~

Comment: no problem, this is what this place is for. If that answer solved your problem, make sure to accept the answer, so others know that a solution has been found

Comment: I tap the Enter button by mistake, can you receive the updated comment?

Comment: if the code is in a controller action and you want to run it outside a controller (or before the controllers are loaded) you need to extract that logic to an engine or something like that. Or, duplicate the logic if you can't make a new engine. Otherwise, I don't see how it could be done without an initializer